# Realm access from incorrect thread Android Error when it is the same thread

Tags: android, multithreading, event-handling, realm

I keep getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
```

However the thread has been interrupted by the time it even touches a realm object, any way of me fixing this?

```
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("CustomSchedule.realm")
            .schemaVersion(42)
            .build();
    mRealm = Realm.getInstance(config);

    mDays = app.getmDays();

    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                while (mDays.isEmpty()) {
                }
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                startActivity();
                handler.post(this);
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();

    return rootView;
}
```

Within the startActivity section I reference realm objects as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Thread to:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                while (mDays.isEmpty()) {
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        startActivity();
                    }
                });
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

And now it works.